# ValueError shape <= 0 for distribution function

Tags: python, distribution

I need to complete a distribution function which looks like this into python:

−∞< x <∞,
P(x)dx= ((1+x^2/n)^-(n+1)/2) * Γ(n+1/2)/Γ(n/2)*(nπ)**1/2 dx, n=1.

So i tried it like this:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import stats
from scipy.special import gammaln
from pylab import *

def studentstPDF(x,n=1):
"""
Call:
   d = studentstPDF(x,n)
Input argument:
   x: float (array)
   n: float, default = 1.0
Output argument:
   p: float
Examples:
   In [1]: studentstPDF(1,1)
   Out[1]: 0.1591549
"""
p = (1+((x**2)/n))**((-n+1)/2) * gamma((n+1)/2) / gamma(n/2) * (n*math.pi)**1/2
p[x<inf] = 0.0
p[x>-inf] = 0.0
return(p)
```

but now I get the error 'ValueError: shape <= 0'

What does that mean? And where am I wrong with my function?

```
In [16]:
studentstPDF(1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-16-ddd6d9df823d>", line 1, in <module>
studentstPDF(1,1)

File "/Users/Veysel/Downloads/Exercise4-2/exercise4.py", line 122, in studentstPDF
p = (1+((x**2)/n))**((-n+1)/2) * gamma((n+1)/2) / gamma(n/2) * (n*math.pi)**1/2

File "mtrand.pyx", line 1871, in mtrand.RandomState.gamma (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:13491)

ValueError: shape <= 0
```

Comment: I don't see the statement with `shape <= 0` or the variable `shape` anywhere in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gamma` function from `scipy.special` is most likely being overwritten by another `gamma` function of another nature, perhaps a random variable function from your mass imports. Import like this instead:

```
from scipy.special import gamma as Gamma
```

and write out your expression like this:

```
p = (1+((x**2)/n))**((-n+1)/2) * Gamma((n+1)/2) / Gamma(n/2) * (n*math.pi)**1/2
```

If you absolutely have to import the same way, use `scipy.special.gamma` in place of your current `gamma` calls and `import scipy`.

Your error itself is a result of attempting to use the multiplicative operator `*` on operands that do not have the same shape.